# Set interval for mod_evasive issue

Tags: apache, centos6, ddos, mod-evasive

I have follow the installation guide [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-against-dos-and-ddos-with-mod_evasive-for-apache-on-centos-7) to install mod_evasive to my apache server. I has tested to set **DOSSiteInterval 1** and **DOSSiteCount 2**, and it is working, but no detail write into log. Somehow, it is not working when I modify to **DOSSiteInterval 60**. I have also checked apache error log, that is no error showing there. Following is my configuration.

```
<IfModule mod_evasive20.c>
    DOSHashTableSize    3097
    DOSPageCount        2
    DOSSiteCount        2
    DOSPageInterval     2
    DOSSiteInterval     6000
    DOSBlockingPeriod   10
    DOSLogDir           "/var/log/mod_evasive/"
    DOSWhitelist        10.168.100.230
</IfModule>
```